# Fast method to read and store serialized objects with pointers and pointers to pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, object

I'm needing a fast method to read and store objects with pointers and pointers to pointers in xml files in c++ . Every object has it's own id , name , and class type.

Comment: Do you have pointers to the base or do you have pointers to the real objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should build a map of pointers to IDs as you serialise your data.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it for pointers, you'll need to define some other method of identifying objects - like GUIDs or some other unique identifiers. In many cases you can just store the objects themselves instead of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [boost::serialize](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)?

I'm pretty sure that it automatically does one level of pointer indirection, and it is capable of writing a "form" of xml.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried boost ,but for size of my project it's too big ( it's big , but it has high simplicity about 4-5 classes )